# VBA Else If statement acting weird

Tags: vba, converters, powerpoint

Alright, so for a PHP script, i need all non-image objects to be converted to images (excluding text) from a .pptx file. As i have quite a lot .pptx files, i tought that i might as well use VBA.

For some reason however, my Else If is acting weird.

```
Sub nieuwemacro()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes

            ' MsgBox (oSh.Type)
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            If oSh.Type = 1 Then
                ConvertShapeToPic oSh
            Else
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    Dim oNewSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent
    oSh.Copy
    Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1)

    With oNewSh
        .Left = oSh.Left
        .Top = oSh.Top
        Do
            .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
        Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
     End With

    oSh.Delete
End Sub
```

The oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) part is just there to see what happens. And this is the result:

[image]

Alright.. So everything is converted properly, except for the big pink ball. So i thought i'd try some other Else ifs. My new Else If statement:

```
If oSh.Type = 1 Then
    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
ElseIf oSh.Type = 14 Then
    ConvertShapeToPic oSh
Else
End If
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

Notice how the code now doesnt convert the green bar at the top? It does that when i add or remove IfElse parts...
I don't know why it does this, could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: just use `Select Case oSh.Type` , it seems more suitable for your code anyway (once you add more scenarios you want to test)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shai! However, i've used a Select Case before, but that gave me the same result...

Comment: Alright, so now in my second For Each i replace all code for the following bit of code:
`If oSh.Type = 1 Then
    MsgBox (oSh.Type)
    oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ' ConvertShapeToPic oSh
End If`

Which does change the pink ball to Red. However, when i remove the ' in front of ConvertShapeToPic oSh, it stops changing the color of the pink ball... I'm really lst right now

Comment: Have you tried using the `Shape.CopyPicture` method with `ActiveSheet.Paste` ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your conditions - you're altering the `oSl.Shapes` collection as you loop through it in a `For Each` loop. Approach this like you would rows in Excel.  Use a `For` loop, and go backward through the indexes.

Comment: @BrentLobbezoo it's working on my presentation, added a bunch of circles, triangles, whatever, colored them pink, orange, blue, green, copied different variations to many slides and thet are all black once I run this code. Read the code in this link, might help you http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00008_Show_the_-Type_of_each_shape_-including_shapes_in_groups-.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub nieuwemacro()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oShs() As Shape
    Dim nShps As Long, iShp As Long

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

        ReDim oShs(1 To oSl.Shapes.Count) As Shape
        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
            ' MsgBox (oSh.Type)
            ' modify the following depending on what you want to
            ' convert
            If oSh.Type = 1 Then
                nShps = nShps + 1
                Set oShs(nShps) = oSh
            End If
        Next
        If nShps > 0 Then
            For iShp = 1 To nShps
                ConvertShapeToPic oShs(iShp)
            Next iShp
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    Dim oNewSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    oSh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    Set oSl = oSh.Parent
    oSh.Copy
    Set oNewSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1)

    With oNewSh
        .Left = oSh.Left
        .Top = oSh.Top
        Do
            .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
        Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
     End With

    oSh.Delete
End Sub
```

---

You may also want to consider the following refactoring:

```
Option Explicit

Sub nieuwemacro()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oShs() As Shape

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        oShs = GetShapes(oSl, msoAutoShape) '<--| gather shapes of given type and...
        ConvertShapesToPics oShs '<--| ...convert them
    Next
End Sub

Function GetShapes(oSl As Slide, shType As MsoShapeType) As Shape()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim nShps As Long

    With oSl.Shapes '<--| reference passed slide Shapes collection
        ReDim oShs(1 To .Count) As Shape '<--| resize shapes array to referenced slide shapes number (i.e. to maximum possible)
        For Each oSh In .Range '<--| loop through referenced slide shapes
            If oSh.Type = shType Then '<--| if its type matches the passed one
                nShps = nShps + 1 '<--| update gathered shapes counter
                Set oShs(nShps) = oSh '<--| fill gathered shapes array
            End If
        Next
    End With
    If nShps > 0 Then '<--| if any shape has been gathered
        ReDim Preserve oShs(1 To nShps) As Shape '<--| resize array properly ...
        GetShapes = oShs '<--| ... and return it
    End If
End Function

Sub ConvertShapesToPics(oShs() As Shape)
    Dim iShp As Long

    If IsArray(oShs) Then '<--| if array has been initialized ...
        For iShp = 1 To UBound(oShs) '<--|... then loop through its elements (shapes)
            ConvertShapeToPic oShs(iShp) '<--| convert current shape
        Next iShp
    End If
End Sub

Sub ConvertShapeToPic(ByRef oSh As Shape)
    With oSh '<--| reference passed shape
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) '<--| change its forecolor
        .Copy '<--| copy it
        With .Parent.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPastePNG)(1) '<--| reference pasted shape
            .Left = oSh.Left '<--| adjust its Left position
            .Top = oSh.Top '<--| adjust its Top position
            Do
                .ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
            Loop Until .ZOrderPosition = .ZOrderPosition
        End With
        .Delete '<--| delete referenced passed shape
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, you may want to shorten down "main" sub by two lines more like follwos

```
Sub nieuwemacro()
    Dim oSl As Slide

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        ConvertShapesToPics GetShapes(oSl, msoAutoShape) '<--| convert shapes of given type
    Next
End Sub
```

where `GetShapes()`, `ConvertShapesToPics()` and `ConvertShapeToPic()` stays the same.

Comment: Wow! This is getting me on the right track. The pink ball is now being converted to an actual image, but when going to the second slide, i'm getting the error  "Subscript out of range (Error 9)" at "Set oShs(nShps) = oSh"

Comment: have you tried the _refactored_ code? I tested it with multiple slides presentation succesfully